# Admob interstitial ad is displaying while app is in background

Tags: flutter, admob, interstitial

When you navigate on an app until an interstitial ad is displayed then you press the `Home button` to send the app to background, and when you bring the app to foreground the interstitial ad is still displayed, is that against AdMob geed-lines?

If yes then how can we detect if the app is sent to the background or closed in Flutter? so we can clear the add

Comment: I’f you close the app you don’t need to remove the ad, it should happen automatically. I don’t know how about going on background. There’s a way you detect when going foreground and I think going background  too but am not sure showing the interstitial on foreground is against the guideline.

Comment: @i6x86 That's what i think too but you never know

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error & I was using the default code provided on developer site.
I was sure there was no mistake from my side.

Then I put the "show ad" code inside the main thread (Handler(Looper.getMainLooper() for android) so that it tries to show ad on main thread & now it's working just fine!

Try to put the method for showing ad inside the main thread using handler or whatever you use in the flutter & it would solve the problem AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

The only mention in the [guidance](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en), of interstitial ads running on background, is this paragraph:

> Do not place interstitial ads on app load and when exiting apps as
>   interstitials should only be placed in between pages of app content.
>   Ads should not be placed in applications that are running in the
>   background of the device or outside of the app environment. It should
>   be clear to the user which application the ad is associated with or
>   implemented on.

And I think it’s clear that we’re talking about apps that are running in background. So if your app enters with the interstitial displayed and when back to foreground there’s the same ad it’s not against the implementation guidance.